# Qt Creator/C++ MySql TableWidget

Tags: c++, mysql, qt-creator

I'm having a little problem once again and maybe you guys could help!

So I'm trying to display database query inside a **tableWidget**.

Problem is that instead of showing up inside the tableWidget that I've created in the GUI, it opens a completely new program with just that query(without my other buttons or labels).

Screenshot of UI: http://i57.tinypic.com/206eety.png

Instead it looks like this: http://i60.tinypic.com/jkvjuh.png

*Question*: How do I get that table inside my tableWidget?

Here is my **main.cpp**:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtSql/QSql>
#include <QtGui/QtGui>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QtSql/QSqlDatabase>
#include <QTableWidget>
#include <QtSql/QSqlError>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <QSqlRecord>
#include <QSqlQueryModel>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])

{


 QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QTableWidget* tableWidget = new QTableWidget();
    tableWidget->setWindowTitle("Connect to Mysql Database");

    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
    db.setHostName("localhost");
    db.setDatabaseName("pizzeria mabo");
    db.setUserName("root");
    db.setPassword("");



 if (!db.open())
    {
        QSqlError err = db.lastError();
        QMessageBox::critical(0, QObject::tr("Database Error"), err.text());
    }




 QSqlQuery query("SELECT * FROM kunden");

        tableWidget->setColumnCount(query.record().count());
        tableWidget->setRowCount(query.size());

        int index=0;
        while (query.next())
        {
        tableWidget->setItem(index,0,new QTableWidgetItem(query.value(0).toString()));
        tableWidget->setItem(index,1,new QTableWidgetItem(query.value(1).toString()));
        tableWidget->setItem(index,2,new QTableWidgetItem(query.value(2).toString()));

        tableWidget->setItem(index,3,new QTableWidgetItem(query.value(3).toString()));
        tableWidget->setItem(index,4,new QTableWidgetItem(query.value(4).toString()));
        tableWidget->setItem(index,5,new QTableWidgetItem(query.value(5).toString()));

        tableWidget->setItem(index,6,new QTableWidgetItem(query.value(6).toString()));
        tableWidget->setItem(index,7,new QTableWidgetItem(query.value(7).toString()));
        tableWidget->setItem(index,8,new QTableWidgetItem(query.value(8).toString()));
        index++;
        }


    tableWidget->show();
        return a.exec();


    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: I would use QSqlQueryModel instead of your method.

Comment: `How do I get that table inside my tableWidget?` Your table widget should be created as a child of the widget that is your form. This should be your MainWindow. You most likely do not want to create it in main().

Comment: So if I put my table items outside my int main() and set it as a child, it should work with my code above?

Comment: By your description in your question you have a tableWidget in your main window. But instead of using that you are creating a second tableWidget as a top level window in main. I would populate the table widget in your main window and instead of the way you do it in your code by filling in each cell use a QSqlQueryModel and let Qt manage the data for you.